AEM Forms Assembler Service object throws Null Pointer
I am trying to write test cases using JUNIT4 for a class (AssemblerHelperService.java) with method (GetTotalPages) that accepts Assembler Service (com.adobe.fd.assembler.service.AssemblerService) instance and a PDF File (com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document) as parameters.
I created a separate Test class (AssemblerHelperServiceTest) with a method getTotalPages, created an instance of Assembler Service and then read a PDF file that i placed in resources folder of my project and then passed them both to the actual method that does the processing.
when i run my test case, i always get Null Pointer exception for the Assembler Service object that i created within my test class, so the same gets passed to the actual method and eventually throws same Null Pointer Exception. Any Help would be much appreciated
I was thinking I might need to have a running local AEM server to retrieve the Assembler Service but did not find a way to do it
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pdfgenerator.core.services.AssemblerHelperService.GetTotalPages(AssemblerHelperService.java:66)
at pdfgenerator.core.services. AssemblerHelperServiceTest.getTotalPages(AssemblerHelperServiceTest.java:55)
Tried declaring the Assembler Service object as @NotNull. Here is my sample Test code.
public class AssemblerHelperServiceTest {

    private static final String processName = "Get Pages Test";

    @Reference
    public ServletConfigurer configurer1;

     @Reference
    private OutputService outputService;

    private inputStream inputStream;

    public AssemblerService asm;

@Test
public void getTotalPages() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {
    @NotNull AssemblerService asm = null;
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/main/resources/test.pdf"));
    Document pdfFile = new Document (is);
    Integer expcount = 18;
    Integer pgcount = null;
//THis is line 55 form the error i mentioned above, "asm" is null here    
pgcount = Integer.valueOf(AssemblerHelperService.GetTotalPages(asm, pdfFile));
    assertEquals(expcount, pgcount);
}

Here is the actual Method I am trying to call from my test method
    public static String GetTotalPages(AssemblerService asm, com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document pdfFile) {
        AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "Inside GetTotalPages");
        Document ddFile = null;
        String pageCount = "";
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        try {
            
            // Create a Document object based on the DDX file
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            ddFile = db.newDocument();
            Element root = (Element) ddFile.createElement("DDX");
            root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/");
            ddFile.appendChild(root);
            //AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "root appended");
            Element documentInformation = (Element) ddFile.createElement("DocumentInformation");
            documentInformation.setAttribute("result", "info.xml");
            documentInformation.setAttribute("source", "flatOutput");
            root.appendChild(documentInformation);
            //AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "documentInformation appended");
            com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document myDDX = ConversionUtils.convertDomToAEMFD(ddFile);
            
            // Create a Map object to store PDF source documents
            Map<String,Object> inputs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            inputs.put("flatOutput", pdfFile);
            
            // Create an AssemblerOptionsSpec object
            AssemblerOptionSpec assemblerSpec = new AssemblerOptionSpec();
            assemblerSpec.setFailOnError(false);
            
            // Submit the job to Assembler service, this is the line 66 from the error, "asm" is null here
            AssemblerResult jobResult = asm.invoke(myDDX, inputs, assemblerSpec);
            Map allDocs = jobResult.getDocuments();
            com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document outDoc = null;
            // Iterate through the map object to retrieve the result PDF document
            for (Iterator i = allDocs.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                //AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "Inside Iterator" + i.toString());
                // Retrieve the Map object�s value
                Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                // Get the key name as specified in the
                // DDX document
                String keyName = (String) e.getKey();
                //AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "keyName=" + keyName);
                if (keyName.equalsIgnoreCase("info.xml")) {
                    Object o = e.getValue();
                    outDoc = (com.adobe.aemfd.docmanager.Document) o;
                    //AdobeStandardLogger.logMessageInfo(processName, "outDoc value" + outDoc);
                }
            }
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = ConversionUtils.convertAEMFDToDom(outDoc);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        pageCount = doc.getElementsByTagName("NumPages").item(0).getTextContent();
        } 
catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError| SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pageCount;
    }

